# In jasperreports how to force page break before a group title if there is no room for any subsequent rows

Tags: jasper-reports, page-break

Is there a way of forcing a page break before a group title if there is no room for ANY of the subsequent rows? It would be nice to be able to query the amount of space left on the current page.

Comment: what happens when we check the Group Properties "start on a new page" ?

Comment: then it will start a new page before each new group. I only want a new page if there is not enough room even for one row following the group header

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a property called **min height to start new page** you will find on the group header. Make this a sum of the height of your detail row and the group header as the lowest amount (more if you want it to have at least 2 rows of detail).  I also suggest setting the **Keep Together** to true as well.