# Table remove column header if no columns on page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a *JasperReports*'s report with some data and a table. The problem is when the table splits on 2 pages sometimes on the first one is only the header of the table. I want it to split (can't use Prevent), but only if it is at least one line of detail (if not, all should move to the next page).

Bad Here:
[image]

Good Here:
[image]

On the first example (the bad one) first header should not be printed.
Ideas?

Comment: can you put some code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your table header into a group header, then follow the advice on the question:
[In jasperreports how to force page break before a group title if there is no room for any subsequent rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440483/in-jasperreports-how-to-force-page-break-before-a-group-title-if-there-is-no-roo)